# Why is the property of an object not being changed?

Tags: javascript

I have an array called fillet_array, which contains objects (currently there is only one object, but this changes throughout the program). This is the output in Chrome:

```
0: Object
  cid: "9351"
  imgsrc: "1a4b1ebb4a31e2104ec1f2bab8539731"
  index: 0
  sku: "TD00060S0"
  width: 0.31
```

This is my code (Note at this time `mattes_number_layers` is 2):

```
console.log(fillet_array);
  if ("undefined" !== typeof(fillet_array) && "undefined" !== typeof(fillet_array[mattes_number_layers - 2]))
  {
    console.log("mattes_number_layers - 2: " + (mattes_number_layers - 2)); //outputs 0
    console.log("mattes_number_layers - 1: " + (mattes_number_layers - 1)); //outputs 1
    console.log(fillet_array[mattes_number_layers - 2]); //outputs Object
    console.log(fillet_array[mattes_number_layers - 2].index); //outputs 0
    fillet_array[mattes_number_layers - 2]['index'] = (mattes_number_layers - 1);//switch index in fillet_array
  } 
  console.log(fillet_array);
```

I am trying to change the index property of the object from 0 to 1, but the code I have does not seem to be working because when I output `fillet_array` again, it is the same as the first one.

Edit: Here is the code creating the fillet object and adding it to the array. This is called before the code above.

```
var fillet = {};
fillet.index = index;
fillet.imgsrc = thumb;
fillet.width = width;
fillet.cid = cid;
fillet.sku = sku;

if (typeof(fillet_array) === "undefined")
{
  fillet_array = [];
}

fillet_array[index] = fillet; //For now index is 0
```

Comment: Have you tried using . notation it shouldn't make a difference but you could try it... `fillet_array[mattes_number_layers - 2].index = (mattes_number_layers - 1);`

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well, but it did not work

Comment: Where is this code located? Can you give more context...

Comment: Your example code works correctly in Firefox 33. Index is updated from 0 to 1 when fillet_array contains the single example object. Providing more context might be necessary.

Comment: It also works in Google Chrome 38

Comment: works for me. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m635nzrk/ Can you reproduce it here?

Comment: @slicedtoad - the first output of fillet_array has the index of 1.

Comment: I closed the question as duplicate of the problem I believe you are experiencing. Happy to reopen if it's not. Actually, this one might be better: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/218196

Comment: @AllisonC Felix is right, the problem is the async console log. If you comment out everything below the first `console.log(fillet_array);` the index is 0.

Comment: use `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/m635nzrk/2/ to get the right results.

Comment: Yes I have discovered this to be the case. Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. :)